# How to set up a testing enviroment with disposable Windows VM images?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, testing, virtual-machine

So I'm responsible for a lot of web developers who work with Macs. Our company doesn't want to shell out for Parallels/VMWare + Windows 7/8/10 licenses for each machine.

In order for them to be able to test on Internet Explorer, I'd like to set up a Linux or Windows box with a few Windows VM images that they can clone, run and throw away after usage. I want them to connect remotely to the VM. The idea is that they'll always find a standardized and reproducible environment, no matter how much they play around with the settings.

What's a good approach for this? I'm thinking of using QEMU so far, but I'm open to other suggestions. Are there any existing solutions for this, so I don't have to script everything myself? Ideally with a Web or other GUI for the users to clone a VM and connect to it?

Comment: Since you tagged IE are you aware of the free vm's here? https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/  Also using Azure you can either through the portal web interface or command line create a new vm, then RDP into it. Not sure if it has to be on premise or not, so figured I'd put it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your limited to what you can use I would look at Linux Terminal Server Project (LTSP) that is free then use the Website Adam mentioned for the images.

These combined would allow for users to remote into a VM and do testing then revert back the image.